# kohana custom validation error message

Tags: validation, kohana, kohana-3

I have a callback within kohana validation. I'm sending error message this way:

```
    public function way(Validate $array, $field)
    {
        if (something)
        {
            $array->error($field, 'super error message', array($array[$field]));
        }
    }
```

It works but when I print out the message

```
echo $errors['field'])
```

it returns `formName.field super error message`

How to get rid of formName.field?

Answer (score 1):

These are messages configured in Kohana Core or in Modules or Application.
You can change them in messages folder
e.g. default validation message are in System -> messages -> validation.php 
you an copy this file in your application and remove :field from them it will get rid of field name.

```
'not_empty'     => ':field must not be empty',
```

change it to

```
'not_empty'     => 'must not be empty',
```